# Inheritence with abstract methods and attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class

Is it possible for an inherited class to call a parents abstract method which refers to the child class without knowing the child class in advance?

```
class AbsParent(object):
    att = 'parent'

    def my_meth():
        return AbsParent.att

class AbsChild(AbsParent):
    att = 'child'

print(AbsChild.my_meth())
```

Obviously the code above will always return `parent` since the parent class is calling its own attribute via `AbsParenet.att`

Is there a clean way the child class can use the Parent class method using inheritance but still reference its own attribute to print `child`? I can only think of something horrible like this

```
 class AbsParent(object):
     att = 'parent'

     def my_meth(abs_class):
          return abs_class.att

 class AbsChild(AbsParent):
    att = 'child'

print(AbsChild.my_meth(AbsChild))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super clear whether you indend `my_meth` to be a class method or not. You're calling with the class `AbsChild` so maybe you want something like:

```
class AbsParent(object):
    att = 'parent'
    @classmethod
    def my_meth(cls):
        return cls.att

class AbsChild(AbsParent):
    att = 'child'

print(AbsChild.my_meth())
```

Alternatively for an instance method:

```
class AbsParent(object):
    att = 'parent'

    def my_meth(self):
        return self.att

class AbsChild(AbsParent):
    att = 'child'

c = AbsChild() # make instance

print(c.my_meth())
```

both print `child`